# How to forward service?wsdl to service.wsdl in Spring WS

Tags: web-services, wsdl, spring-ws

At the first sorry for my awful English. I have following piece of Spring WS configuration:

```
@Configuration
class WSConfig {

    ...

    @Bean
    Wsdl11Definition wsdlSchema() {

        SimpleWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("service.wsdl"));

        return wsdl11Definition;
    }
}
```

So I can get WSDL file using URL ***/service.wsdl**.

Is it possible to add URL forwarding ***/service?wsdl --> */service.wsdl**  cause of some WS clients use URL */service?wsdl.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is extending MessageDispatcherServlet

```
class CustomMessageDispatcherServlet extends MessageDispatcherServlet {

private static final String WSDL_SUFFIX_NAME = ".wsdl";

private Map<String, WsdlDefinition> wsdlDefinitions;

CustomMessageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {

    super();
    setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
    setTransformSchemaLocations(false);
}

@Override
protected void initStrategies(ApplicationContext context) {

    super.initStrategies(context);
    initWsdlDefinitions(context);
}

private void initWsdlDefinitions(ApplicationContext context) {

    wsdlDefinitions = BeanFactoryUtils
            .beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(
                    context, WsdlDefinition.class, true, false);
}

// here with dealing with "wsdl" parameter in HTTP GET request
@Override
protected WsdlDefinition getWsdlDefinition(HttpServletRequest request) {

    if (HttpTransportConstants.METHOD_GET.equals(request.getMethod()) &&
            (request.getRequestURI().endsWith(WSDL_SUFFIX_NAME) || request.getParameter("wsdl") != null)) {

        String fileName = WebUtils.extractFilenameFromUrlPath(request.getRequestURI());
        return wsdlDefinitions.get(fileName);

    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

}